# full calendar event click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, fullcalendar, jquery-click-event

I have updated my [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) plugin to the version 2.2.3 and now the [eventClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) is not getting triggered. I am using the jquery version 1.7.2 and jquery ui 1.8.18.

Below is how I am calling the fullcalendar: eventClick is not working, but the dayClick is working fine.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
editable: true,
height: '700',
events: [
{
title: 'My Event',
start: '2014-12-05'
}
],
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
alert('day click');
},
eventClick:
 function (event, jsEvent) {
            alert('event clicked');
        }
    });
```

Comment: What the error in your console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/AzmJv/16/ You want something like this?

Comment: Kindly change your Jquery plugin with latest and check, thats the problem creator

Comment: Thanks i have updated all my Jquery to latest and now it is working fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fullcalendar behaves abruptly without any errors and warnings when the jquery ui version is not up to date. So You need to update your jquery ui version preferably to 1.11...

Comment: Download the recent version of jquery from jquery official downloads page and then replace your older jquery files with the recent one in your your project folder. Update the references in your project. Or you can directly copy the the recent jquery cdn urls and replace the the old references with the copied urls.

Comment: I don't use jQuery UI at all. Why does it not work for me?

Comment: @Debiprasad how are you using the plugin then? can you provide your code snippet.

Comment: @Krishna I am using jQuery. Not jQuery UI. BTW, I found my mistake in my code and fixed it.